Comparing two unequal groups over time?
I am new to rstudio and statistics in general so bear with me. I am trying to compare the changes over time between two different variables, but they come from very different sample sizes.
I am looking at the difference between field sample measurements and those taken in the lab. They are measured in different units, but should be correlated because they are measuring the same thing essentially.
I have a dataset "Probe" where the variable of interest "value" is measured.
This should correlate with my "value" variables from my other data set "Field".
What type of statistical test would give me the analysis I am looking for? I am trying to see whether peaks in the "Field" value correlates with peaks in the "Probe" value and so on. I am trying to track over time whether they are showing similar trends. I want to do something like a correlation but can not because the "Probe" data consists of 1606 observations and the "Field" data consists of 197 observations so they differ in length and can not be correlated (as far as I know from my research so far).

You are correct that to determine the correlation coefficient you must have a that each observations is paired.
To run a correlation analysis, one option would be to determine the 197 points in the "Probe" dataset which are "paired" in the "Field" data. These being points were measured "closest" together with respect to the study design, and use those compute the correlation.
